# Iterate over a backbone collection based on properties of models in an elegant way

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection and based on an attribute of models inside collection I iterate over the collection and show it in the UI.

The logic is, if the model has property `isNewCar` as `true`, I'll first show them all in UI, followed by a separator then i'll show all models having property `isNewCar` as `false`.

```
this.cars.forEach(function (car, index) 
{
    if(car.isNewCar()){ //IF A NEW CAR
        //some logic.
        //Attach current view in DOM with this model's properties           
    }   
});

//Here, Attach some separator in DOM

this.cars.forEach(function (car, index) 
{
    if(!car.isNewCar()){ //IF 'NOT' A NEW CAR
        //some logic.
        //Attach current view in DOM with this model's properties           
    }
});
```

This looks messy and I understand its not so elegant, can someone suggest a better way to replace above code with some elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest have a common rendering logic to render the items in a separate function say renderCars() and filter the collection as below

```
 function filterCars(isNew) {
   var isNewCar = isNew
   return function(car) {
      return (car.isNewCar() === isNewCar);
   }
 }

 renderCars (this.cars.filter(filterCars(true)) );
 renderCars (this.cars.filter(filterCars(false)) );
```

All we have done above is created a helper function filterCars that takes a boolean to decide if we need new cars or not. This helper function returns a function that is used to filter the cars .

Backbone filter uses the underscore filter that returns a new array of the filtered results. I am passing this to the common render function.

I did not test this but this should help clear out some repeated code.

Comment: in `filterCars` function how is `car` variable accessible? It is not right.

Comment: It is . the return function will be used as the function for the filter method which will be passing in the car. (Filter API )[http://underscorejs.org/#filter]

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle i created to explain the above code .. try to uncomment the last line in the code and see the results : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkuruvada/r64qgaxt/7/)

Comment: Though I didn't use exactly what you suggested. But the `filter` function came quite handy.